# Adding Websockets to Django server deployed on Azure Web App Service

Tags: python, django, azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service

I have a Django application which starts a server using the websockets https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html library for Python. The manage.py file looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import asyncio
import threading

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        os.environ.setdefault(
            'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',
            'UPH_Chart_Re.settings')
        try:
            from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
        except ImportError as exc:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            ) from exc
        try:
            from WebsocketClass import StartServer
            x = threading.Thread(group=None, target=StartServer, name="Websocket Thread")
            x.daemon=True
            x.start()
        except ImportError as exce:
            raise ImportError("Importing WebsocketsClass failed") from exce
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

The StartServer function starts a websocket server using asyncio:

```
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    start_server = websockets.serve(Receive, "localhost", 5001)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

The Django webpages and websocket server work perfectly on my local machine. The problem I'm running into now is that when deploying to Azure Web App Service, I don't seem to be able to access the sockets. **My Web App Service has Websockets set to enabled**, and I get no errors on my deployment. However, I can't seem to connect to the websocket at all.

I have tried setting the port to 443, which is considered a forbidden port since it's below 1024. I have tried using `os.environ['PORT']` to retrieve a port from the host, but that port is already in use.